# How can I add add margin on table body?

Tags: html, css

How do I put margin in header cell and round padding in `tbody`?

My `HTML`.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-comparison nobottommargin">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th >Starter</th>
            <th>Professional</th>
            <th>Business</th>
            <th>Business</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Space</td>
            <td>1 GB</td>
            <td>5 GB</td>
            <td>20 GB</td>
            <td>20 GB</td>
        </tr>                 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I want to achieve.

[image: Round green tabs with space between them.]

Comment: maybe : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing will be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I would use these css rules:

```
thead th {
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 20px;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do that

```
table{
        border-spacing: 10px;
      }
thead th:not(:first-child){
        background-color: #058ba2;
        padding: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 15px;
        border-top-right-radius: 15px;
        color:white;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
.table thead tr th:not(:first-child),
.table tbody tr td:not(:first-child){
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

The :not selector prevents the first column to set a padding-left of 20px. I assumed that you would like to leave the top corner 'blank'.